# Creating a Video using opencv 2.4.1 anaconda python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

img2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg')

img3 = cv2.imread('3.jpg')

height , width , layers =  img1.shape

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')

video = cv2.VideoWriter('videococo.avi',fourcc,1,(width,height))

cv2.VideoWriter(img1)

cv2.VideoWriter(img2)

cv2.VideoWriter(img3)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

video.release()
```

That's my python's code, when i run it

gives me TypeError: Required argument 'fourcc' (pos 2) not found

and sometimes it gives me Video with 0KB not opening file.

Comment: Have you tried
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'). It seems to be the way to do it according to the docs http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Comment: its giving me an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter_fourcc'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code as:

```
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
img3 = cv2.imread('3.jpg')

height , width , layers =  img1.shape     
fps=20
video = cv2.VideoWriter("videococo.avi", cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX'), fps, (img1.shape[1], img1.shape[0]))
video.write(img1)
video.write(img2)
video.write(img3)


video.release()
```

In your code, you were creating the 'video' object but were trying to access it in a static way, thus your fourcc params weren't read